# Select keys with same length of value which is highest count list in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a sorted `defaultdict` like:

```
k = {'a':[3,4,5] , 'x':[5,4,11] , 'c':[1,3,4] , 'l': [2,3], 'h':[1]}
```

What I want is to get only keys with highest or higesht equal length in value.

Expected output:

```
{'a':[3,4,5] , 'x':[5,4,11] , 'c':[1,3,4]} or [a,b,c]
```

I have used numpy to get true values in an array and then extract it
my code:

```
z = np.array(arr)     #arr variable has the size of lists i.e arr = [3,3,3,2,1]
    p = len(z[z == z[0]])    #To Check how many highest count is SAME and store the count in p variable
    print(z >= z[0])
    print(list(k)[0:p])
```

Output :-

```
True True True False False

[a,x,c]
```

So my question is, is there any way to do this without using numpy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to calculate the maximum length, then use a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {'a':[3,4,5] , 'x':[5,4,11] , 'c':[1,3,4] , 'l': [2,3], 'h':[1]}

max_len = max(map(len, d.values()))

res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == max_len}

print(res)

{'a': [3, 4, 5], 'x': [5, 4, 11], 'c': [1, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Excellent One.! Thank you